# How to separate files using dask groupby on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a large set of csv files (`file_1.csv`, `file_2.csv`), separated by time period, that cant be fit into memory. Each file will be in the format mentioned below.

```
| instrument | time | code     | val           |
|------------|------|----------|---------------|
| 10         | t1   | c1_at_t1 | v_of_c1_at_t1 |
| 10         | t1   | c2_at_t1 | v_of_c2_at_t1 |
| 10         | t2   | c1_at_t2 | v_of_c1_at_t2 |
| 10         | t2   | c3_at_t2 | v_of_c3_at_t2 |
| 11         | t1   | c4_at_t1 | v_of_c4_at_t1 |
| 11         | t1   | c5_at_t1 | v_of_c5_at_t1 |
| 12         | t2   | c6_at_t2 | v_of_c6_at_t2 |
| 13         | t3   | c9_at_t3 | v_of_c9_at_t3 |
```

Each file is about instrument logs that are consistent in their format. There are set of instruments which can emit different codes(`code`) at a given timestamp(`time`). The value of that `code` at a given `time` for a given instrument is saved in `val` column

I would like to split each file (ex: `file_1.csv`) using the `instrument`  column(ex: `10`) and then join the files extracted for the instrument (ex: `10`) across all files (`file_1.csv`, `file_2.csv`)

I am thinking about using `dask` groupby operation on the `instrument` column. Is there any alternative or better approach to do it instead of using `groupby` or better way to extract the files by `instrument`?

Code that I have written to do the above operation is

```py
import glob
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()

def read_files(files):

    files = glob.glob(files)

    for f in files:

        df = dd.read_csv(f, blocksize='256MB')
        unique_inst = df['instrument'].unique()
        gb = df.groupby('instrument')  

        for v in unique_inst:
            gb.get_group(v).to_parquet(f'{v}_{f[:-4]}.parquet')

    pass
```

Once I have the files in `f'{v}_{f[:-4]}.parquet'` format, I can concat them using `pandas` extracted from all the files (`file_1.csv`, `file_2.csv`)

The final file for instrument `10` should be something like below where the observations at `t7`, `t9` are concatenated from observations for instrument `10` in other files

```
time | code     | val           |
-----|----------|---------------|
t1   | c1_at_t1 | v_of_c1_at_t1 |
t1   | c2_at_t1 | v_of_c2_at_t1 |
t2   | c1_at_t2 | v_of_c1_at_t2 |
t2   | c3_at_t2 | v_of_c3_at_t2 |
t7   | c4_at_t7 | v_of_c4_at_t7 |
t9   | c5_at_t9 | v_of_c5_at_t9 |
```

Comment: It's not clear to me if a single file like`file1.csv` fitting in memory?

Comment: None of the `csv` files can be fit into memory as the size of each file is more 100 GB

Comment: Wow this changes things a bit. Questions: 1. what are the datatypes? 2. for one file only where `df` is a dask.dataframe is `df.groupby(""instrument")["val"].sum().compute()`  giving you a memory error?

Comment: Sorry if my first statement in the question caused any confusion as I mentioned that large csv files `cant be fit into memory`. All the column values are stored as strings in the csvs. I can do `df.groupby(""instrument")["val"].sum().compute()`, but each column is a string, `sum` will concatenate the column values

Comment: Is it normal that *value* is a `str` or you eventually need to transform to float? What about *time* and  *instrument*? Converting type will help you to save lot of memory.

Comment: If you can try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve) and try to explain what do you want to achieve

Comment: The value of `time` should eventually be converted to `datetime` format,  `value` to `float` format. For other columns ('instrument` and `code`) can be in `str` format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202821/discussion-between-rtm-and-rpanai).

Comment: I added a brief example of the output format that I am looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you need to achieve but I don't think you need any group by for your problem. It seems to me a simple filtering issue.

You can just loop over all your files and create new instrument files and append on those.

Also I don't have example files to experiment but I think you can also just use pandas with chunksize to read large csv files.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

# maybe play around to get better performance 
chunksize = 1000000

files = glob.glob('./file_*.csv')
for f in files:

     for chunk in pd.read_csv(f, chunksize=chunksize):
         u_inst = chunk['instrument'].unique()

         for inst in u_inst:
             # filter instrument data
            inst_df = chunk[chunk.instrument == inst]
            # filter columns
            inst_df = inst_df[['time', 'code', 'val']]
            # append to instrument file
            # only write header if not exist yet
            inst_file = f'./instrument_{inst}.csv'
            file_exist = os.path.isfile(inst_file)
            inst_df.to_csv(inst_file, mode='a', header=not file_exist)
```

Comment: Thanks. One caveat of this approach is that we are looping through each chunk however number of `u_inst` are available. What is your opinion on reading each line and appending it to the correct `inst_file` ? or using the same approach mentioned above with `chunksize` of `1`

Comment: The bottleneck in such operations is usually IO. A bigger chunk size allows to read more at once to your memory. The filtering itself on the chunk is a lookup and is super fast. Therefore I would recommend to use a large chunk size. Maybe even larger what I proposed. I would be surprised if chunksize 1 would result in good results.

Comment: I tried the same approach with chunksize =1. The process is very slow compared to reading in chunks and then filtering by inst

Answer (score 2):

In case every single file fits in memory you can try this:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
```

## Generate dummy files

```py
fldr_in = "test_in"
fldr_out = "test_out"

N = int(1e6)
for i in range(10):
    fn = f"{fldr_in}/file{i}.csv"
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(fn), exist_ok=True)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"instrument":np.random.randint(10,100,N),
                       "value":np.random.rand(N)})
    df.to_csv(fn, index=False)
```

## Define function

The following function save to parquet for every single instrument in the path `fldr_out/instrument=i/fileN.csv`

```py
def fun(x, fn, fldr_out):
    inst = x.instrument.unique()[0]
    filename = os.path.basename(fn)
    fn_out = f"{fldr_out}/instrument={inst}/{filename}"
    fn_out = fn_out.replace(".csv", ".parquet")
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(fn_out), exist_ok=True)
    x.drop("instrument", axis=1)\
     .to_parquet(fn_out, index=False)
```

and you can use it with a group by

```py
for f in files:
    fn = f"{fldr_in}/{f}"
    df = pd.read_csv(fn)
    df.groupby("instrument").apply(lambda x: fun(x, fn, fldr_out))
```

## Performing Analysis with dask

Now you can use `dask` to read the results and perform your analysis

```py
df = dd.read_parquet(fldr_out)
```